# Как аннотировать Entity для создания таблицы отношений?

Tags: java, sql, spring-data, hsqldb

Я создаю приложение с `DataJpa`.

У меня есть сущность **Dish**:

```
CREATE TABLE dishes
(
    id    INTEGER GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS SEQUENCE GLOBAL_SEQ PRIMARY KEY,
    name  VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
);
```

Имеется также сущность **Menu**:

```
CREATE TABLE menus
(
    id    INTEGER GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS SEQUENCE GLOBAL_SEQ PRIMARY KEY,
    date  DATE    NOT NULL,
);
```

И ещё я сделал таблицу их отношений:

```
CREATE TABLE menu_dishes
(
    dish_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    menu_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT menu_dishes_menu_dish_idx UNIQUE (menu_id, dish_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (dish_id) REFERENCES dishes (id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY (menu_id) REFERENCES menus (id) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

Почему бы просто не сделать в Dish `FK` на Menu, зачем делать эту третью таблицу? Всё потому что я хочу, чтобы для каждого нового Menu не надо было создавать новые Dish, когда можно было бы взять старые и заставить их ссылаться на Menu, *т.е. вместо создания новых Dish, я хочу создавать новые отношения*.

У меня возникла проблема с маппингом. Menu я сделал вот так:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "menus")
public class Menu {

    @CollectionTable(name = "menu_dishes", joinColumns = "menu_id")
    @ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<Dish> dishes;
```

Но что-то мне подсказывает, что этого недостаточно. Что мне ещё необходимо сделать, чтобы реализовать такую таблицу отношений? Какие изменения мне нужно сделать в классах **Dish** и **Menu**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Для таблицы отношений используется аннотация `@ManyToMany`

С её помощью для каждого нового Menu не надо будет создавать новую сущность Dish, когда можно использовать старую. Для связывания сущностей `ManyToMany` необходимо прописать следующие аннотации в одной сущности:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "menus")
public class Menu extends AbstractBaseEntity {

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
            name = "menu_dishes",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "menu_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "dish_id")
    )
    private List<Dish> dishes;
```

и в другой:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "dishes")
public class Dish extends AbstractNamedEntity {

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "dishes")
    private List<Menu> menu;
```

Причём не имеет значения, в какой из них будут прописаны конкретные аннотации. В `joinColumn` указывается колонка, на которую будет маппится целевая сущность. В `inverseJoinColumns` в свою очередь указывается колонка, на которую будет маппится связанная сущность.